# Form don't accept DateTime format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, date, datetime

Need some help here. I have the standard edit form the default visual studio application, and when I use the form to edit some DB row, in the datetime it shows me a date like "01-01-0001 00:00:00", and to save the edit i have to change the date to "01/01/0001 00:00:00". Its boring, and as it is the date bringed by mvc itself, it should work if I don't touch it right? My code is the follow:

Model

```
    public class Result
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Data/Hora")]
        public DateTime Datahora { get; set; }
    }
```

View (where the form is)

```
@model ApdlModel.Entities.Resultado

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2></h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Editar Resultado</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Datahora, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Datahora, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Basically, when the mvc gets the value from the BD, it brings the "01/01/0001 00:00:00" format, but when I try to save in that format it dont allow me. Why? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Possible post your data saving logic here.

Comment: @SelvaTS, i dont have data saving logic. Is something that I have to implement separatly?

Comment: Try to use fiddler to see what is actually sent over the channel. Browsers and MVC sometimes have a different opinion about culture and (therefore) datetime formats.

Comment: Please be more specific other than "it dont allow me".  What happens?  Do you get an error message, and if so what is it?

Comment: @MattJohnson no error message, it simply brings to the form the date in the format 01-01-0001 00:00:00, and only accepts the form submit with the format 01/01/0001 00:00:00 (note the - and /), and I dont now where this is defined on mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is because your date is not nullable? If it is not nullable you should consider setting default value.

Comment: Andrei, and where I should define the default value? On the model?

Comment: @danielpm probably in controller, when you create your model